# How to bring Android activity to the front without bringing app to front if it is running in background?

Tags: android, background, mobile-application

I have an app that may run in the background. While it is running, it may bring a certain activity to the front. However, when the app brings the activity to the front, if the app is currently running at background, I do not want Android to bring the app itself to the front, just do it at background. The reason being is I do not want my app to interrupt what the customer is doing at the moment.

The following is my code that launches the activity.

```
Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intentLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentLogin);
```

The issue with the above code is every time when it is called, it always bring my app to the front even the app is running at background, that is, annoy my customer.

My question is, is there a way that I can quietly bring the activity to the front? If my app is running in front, thats great --- the customer see the new activity straight away. If my app is running at background, I want to quietly bring the activity to the front when app is running in background, and next time when my customer resume the app, they will see the new activity I brought forward.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: so you want to they see another activity onResume() of MainActivity?

Comment: It's not necessarily MainActivity. The thing is I will issue a notification to my customer that tells the current account is logged out. And when customer comes back they see login page instead of the last page they left. If the customer is using my app in front, they will see login page when notification comes in. If the app is running in background, the customer will see login page next time when they resume the app.

Comment: so you force log out onPause or onDestroy?

Comment: What I am looking for is a solution that can quietly bring a specific activity to front, without bringing app to foreground if it is running at background.

Comment: I get what you want. You want to notify the user without bringing your app to the front, thus showing one specific activity just for that notification with most probably just a message and an OK button. You want the behavior of an Alarm. I'm looking for the same answer, do you have it by now? I need the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

如果我没理解错的话：

- App background and usual player.

When user logged out , you can clear the user data saved in local and show a notification.And when the notification is clicked, start `LoginActivity`.

- App background and unusual player.

When the notification shows ,the user do not click it instead of run the app.You can check the user data whether existing or not by `onResume()`in `BaseActivity`.If not ,start `LoginActivity`.

- App foreground.

clear user data and force to start `LoginActivity`.

**If you don't like the solution above(the best user experence I think),try this:**

- In `onCreate()` in the specific Activity ,use `moveTaskToBack(true)` to hide the intent.But remember to check whether the app is running background or foreground.you can refer to [this](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html).

Comment: Forget about login or log out. What I am looking for is a solution that can quietly bring a specific activity to front, without bringing app to foreground if it is running at background.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, I suggest this:
User leaves your app, and when user come back to your app you want to show another activity instead of `.MainActivity`
define another activity as Main and with NoDisplay theme.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then define your normal activities. In MainActivity class define a `static variable`. for example

```
public static boolean appRun = false;
```

**onCreate()** of **SecondActivity** change its value to **true**.

```
class SecondActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Saved){
super.onCreate(Saved);
MainActivity.appRun = true;
}
}
```

and onPause set `this.finish();` to avoid not resuming to SecondActivity and force to start from MainActivity.
then onCreate() or onResume() of MainActivity check it s value and navigate to another activity.

```
  if(appRun == true){
    /*it means user went to SecondActivity and you want to display another*/
    startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));
    }
else{
//this is first time so navigate to SecondActivity
}
```

Also If you can use Fragments this solution can work for that too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your understanding is partially correct. Yes I do want to display another activity when user comes back to my app, however, it is not from MainActivity. It could be any activity that user left last time when they push my app into the background.

Comment: Ok then call this.finish() onPause() of each activity.

Comment: Thank you. Is there something like "delegate" in Android like iOS app?

Comment: If you mean to communicate between classes, you should use Intent().putExtra();